# Control center on premise deployment

Tags: gridgain

I have deployed control center on-premise on docker using below link.

https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/on-premise/installation/docker

When I start my cluster, control center URI pointing to the hosted control center (SaaS: https://control.gridgain.com) instead of on-premise control center.

How can I change/update the URI?

[08:39:41] Established websocket connection with Control Center: https://control.gridgain.com
[08:39:41]

> > > +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> > > | Open the link in a browser to monitor your cluster:                                               |
> > > | https://control.gridgain.com/go/token_number                             |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `management.sh` script:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783361/control-center-on-premise-deployment
```

It is described [here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/getting-started/connect/connect-gridgain-cluster#control-center-uri).

The script is built-in with GridGain platform, and comes with the Control Center Agent for Apache Ignite.